# Django & Python: AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'detail'

Tags: python, django

File **url.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allblogs, name='allblogs'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

File **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Blog

def allblogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'blogs':blogs})

    def detail(request, blog_id):
        detailblog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
        return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'blog':detailblog})
```

I got AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'detail'. The error was in "portfolio-project\blog\urls.py", line 7, in   path('int:blog_id/', views.detail, name='detail'),

Comment: The `def detail` is indented *in* the `allblogs` function, so it is an inner function. You should unindent it.

Answer (score 0):

You are indenting detail function. So, it can not find where the function is.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Blog

def allblogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'blogs':blogs})

    def detail(request, blog_id):
        detailblog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
        return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'blog':detailblog})
```

but it should  be:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Blog

def allblogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'blogs':blogs})

def detail(request, blog_id):
    detailblog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'blog':detailblog})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and found the issue was caused by a mix of tabs and spaces.